# Moving a VirtualBox to a new PC

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox machine on PC running Windows 7 64 (host OS) with an Ubuntu Guest. How can I move this to another PC?

What files or options should I use to preserve everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export it by doing the following:

> File > Export Appliance > {Choose Virtual Machine} > {Choose File path where you want the .ova file}

When you come to import it on the new PC, just do:

> File > Import Appliance > Open Appliance > {Browse to your .ova file}

Import wizard will also display a checkbox for creating a new MAC address for every network interface in your virtual machine. Set it if you're planning to use the old and the new VM at the same time in the same lan, to avoid IP address conflicts. If after that your new VM can't connect see also: [Proper way for changing MAC address in a linux VM?](https://superuser.com/q/444677/85364)

Comment: @gerlos thank you for the edit. I didn't even know that. Now I know why I keep getting conflicts.